# Can Cauchy's Integral Theorem thought of as a special case of the Residue Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

From what I learned from my complex analysis class, Cauchy's integral theorem says that a contour integral of a analytic function in a given region is equal to zero. On the other hand, the Residue Theorem tells me that a contour integral of a function in a given region is equal to $2\pi$*(sum of residues inside) if I'm not mistaken. And while reviewing for my final exam I just got curious if one can see Cauchy's theorem above just as a special case of the Residue Theorem, with the restriction of the integrand being analytic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, you can. ${}{}$